# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED ADB0010

Tags: android

i have a problem with my app, with an emualtor API30 i have no problems but starting an emulator with api 31 Android 12.0 on Visual Studio, i every time got following error

```
Error       ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl389525493.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #158): com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 357
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 206
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 223
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<InstallPackage>d__105.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line 339
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<InstallPackage>d__105.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line 356
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FastDeploy.<RunTaskAsync>d__100.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/Tasks/FastDeploy.cs:line 213           0
```

Can someone help me with this error. I dont know what i can do, i deleted /bin and obj. Folder but dont work.

Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

As the log message says, you need to define the `android:exported` code in the Manifest for BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity, because you are targeting Android SDK 31. Go to the manifest and add this in your BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity tag

```
android:exported="true"
```

or

```
android:exported="false"
```

based on what you need. Read more about the 'exported' parameter [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported)